# nginx rewrite rule for a variable subdomain

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Please help me create a rewrite rule in Nginx so that this URL https://subdomain.domain.com/api gets re-written to https://subdomain-api.domain.com

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Asking questions at ServerFault require some effort on attempted solutions from the people asking. This is not a "implement thing X for free" service.

Answer (score 1):

By nginx documentation it's better to use locations instead of creating rewrite rules. Something like this should help you:

```
server {
    server_name subdomain.domain.com;
    location /api {
        return 301 https://subdomain-api.domain.com$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can I make subdomain a variable for example: 
https://sub2.domain.com > https://sub2-api.domain.com
https://sub3.domain.com > https://sub3-api.domain.com
and so on..

Answer (score 0):

As per the other answer, it's better to use redirects, but you should also ensure that the HTTP scheme, and any URL parameters are preserved, like so:

As per your comment, if you know how many subdomains you're going to have, it's easiest to just define them all:

```
server {
    server_name subdomain1.domain.com;
    location /api { 
        return 301 $scheme://sub1-api.domain.com/$1$is_args$query_string; 
    }
}

server {
    server_name subdomain2.domain.com;
    location /api { 
        return 301 $scheme://sub2-api.domain.com/$1$is_args$query_string; 
    }
}
```

Alternately this might work:

```
server {
    server_name: subdomain1.domain.com subdomain2.domain.com subdomain3.domain.com;
    location /api { 
        if ($host ~* (.*)\.domain\.com) {
            set $sub_domain $1;
            return 301 $scheme://$sub_domain-api.domain.com/$1$is_args$query_string; 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, can I make subdomain a variable for example: sub2.domain.com > sub2-api.domain.com sub3.domain.com > sub3-api.domain.com and so on..